# SQL, ¿Como sumar valores de dos tablas y agruparlos por fecha?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

llevo días estancado en esta consulta que seguro para vosotros sera cosa fácil.
Tengo dos tablas.

tablaFacturas

[image: tablaFacturas]

y la tablaTicket

[image: tablaTicket]

Lo que no consigo es me devuelva la suma de las facturas y tickets agrupados por fecha, ejemplo:

2020-01-01    800
2020-01-02    250
2020-01-03   1395
2020-01-04   1125

Yo suponía que seria algo así, pero ni esto ni todo lo que he probado funciona:

```
SELECT fechaFactura AS cFecha, SUM(totalFactura) FROM tablacabecerafacturas WHERE fechaFactura >= '2020/01/01' AND fechaFactura <= '2020/01/08' UNION ALL SELECT fechaTicket AS cFecha, SUM(totalTicket) FROM tablacabeceratickets WHERE fechaTicket >= '2020/01/01' AND fechaTicket <= '2020/01/08' GROUP BY cFecha
```

Cualquier ayuda/pista sera agradecida.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando operas con SQL los SELECT, JOIN, UNION etc funcionan como tablas, solo tienes que aplicar los operadores donde toca (No pongo los WHERE porque realmente no afectan, ya los pondrás tú)

```
SELECT fechaFactura AS cFecha, totalFactura as cImporte FROM tablacabecerafacturas 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT fechaTicket AS cFecha, totalTicket as cImporte FROM tablacabeceratickets
```

te genera una "tabla" (lógica, no es que físicamente exista pero puedes operar como si existiera) con los campos cFecha, cImporte.

Luego se trata de hacer la consulta sobre esa tabla

```
SELECT cFecha, SUM(cImporte) FROM (
   SELECT fechaFactura AS cFecha, totalFactura as cImporte FROM tablacabecerafacturas 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT fechaTicket AS cFecha, totalTicket as cImporte FROM tablacabeceratickets) tabla_interna
GROUP BY cFecha;
```

El WHERE lo puedes poner o bien en los selects internos o en el externo, no tengo claro si habría diferencia de rendimiento.

Comment: Hola SJuan76, usando tu código me muestra el error "#1248 - Cada tabla derivada debe tener su propio alias" , ¿que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y la explicación.

Comment: Un poco de Google nos muestra que mysql pide que al hacer un subselect (usar un SELECT en el FROM) se le de un nombre a la tabla "lógica" que se define. Mira el edit.

Comment: YA!! la solucion:

SELECT cFecha, SUM(cImporte) FROM (
   SELECT fechaFactura AS cFecha, totalFactura as cImporte FROM tablacabecerafacturas 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT fechaTicket AS cFecha, totalTicket as cImporte FROM tablacabeceratickets 
) AS tablaTemporal GROUP BY cFecha;

Gracias SJuan76 que me has dado la dirección correcta. ;)